# Session expiring when reloading page in django auth

Tags: django, django-authentication

Whenever I reload my page clicking enter in the adresss bar URL of browser or opening the same URL in another tab, the session seems to be expired. I mean my page is navigating to Login Page.

Here is my view. The below view will render in one HTML page which is index.html. Whenever a user login's Username/Password login form is displayed other wise it says thank you for login. So this functionality is working fine.

```
def index(request):
     if request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/myapp/')

     if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                username = form.cleaned_data['username']
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            if request.user.is_authenticated():
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/myapp/')
            else:
                user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
            return shortcuts.render_to_response('index.html',locals(),
                                    context_instance = context.RequestContext(request))
     else:
            form = UserLoginForm

return shortcuts.render_to_response('index.html',locals(),
                                    context_instance = context.RequestContext(request))
```

For your reference I have installed below middle ware classes in my app.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
```

Can some one help me on this please

-Ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a call to the [login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login) function because this function is responsible for saving the user's ID in the session, like so:

```
else:
    user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request, user)
    else:
        ...
```

Comment: Now my browser says like this  This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at http://localhost:8090/myapp/ has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer. I have cleared all the cookies and reloaded but still the above message is coming

Comment: Never mind, I solved it myself by replacing return HttpResponseRedirect('/myapp/') after is_authenticated() with return shortcuts.render_to_response('index.html',locals(),                          context_instance = context.RequestContext(request))

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're using 'authenticate' method and not 'login' method.What you're trying to do will be accomplished by using 'login' instead of 'authenticate'.When you use 'login',it saves user's ID in the session.See this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login